# Суховіз чи суховантаж?

Tags: вибір-слова, неологізми

На позначення вантажного транспортного судна, призначеного для перевезення сухих, не наливних, вантажів, у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sukhovantazh) наводиться назва *суховантаж*. 
[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) пропонує переклад аналогічного російського слова як *суховоз (суховіз)* або *балкер*. В СУМ-11 таке слово відсутнє. 
За результатами [пошуку](https://www.google.com.tr/search?rlz=1C1VFKB_en__709__709&ei=mszyWsnMGoGQmwWqkL7YBQ&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%20&oq=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...114972.114972.0.116280.1.1.0.0.0.0.281.281.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.XkWAe9nlBMI), *сухові/оз* вживаний украй рідко, хоча логіка у його створенні є.

Чи є потреба відмовитися від вживання *суховантаж* на користь *суховозу*?

Answer (score 1):

Не варто відмовлятися від слова *"суховантаж"* на користь *"суховіз"*. Адже слово *"суховіз*" на противагу "*суховантажу"* відсутне в словниках української мови.

[Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53409/995389.html) і [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sukhovantazh) подають лише визначення *суховантаж*

> ***Суховантаж*** -у, ч. 1. Сухий вантаж. 2. Вантажне транспортне судно,
>   признач. для перевезення сухих, не наливних, вантажів; суховантажне
>   судно.

Answer (score 0):

Обидва слова мають право на існування. Згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6) "Суховантаж" - це судно "річкового або морського базування", а от слово "суховоз", на мою думку, також може вживатися, щоб позначити "судно для перевезення сухого вантажу", накшталт "[нафтовоза](http://sum.in.ua/s/naftovoz)" чи "[контейнеровоза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7)". Однак, все ж таки слово "суховантаж" є в СУМі та у Вікіпедії, а також вживається в офіційних документах та в новинах, тому гадаю, що краще вживати його.

Comment: Якщо Ви мали на увазі, що між _сухов{і,о}з_ і _суховантаж_ є різниця в значеннях, то я особисто не зрозумів, у чому саме вона полягає.